# SQLAlchemy conditional relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have 2 db models like this:

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    show_start = db.Column(db.Integer)
    show_times = db.relationship('ShowTime')

class ShowTime(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    theatre_id = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date_time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'))
```

Is it possible to make the `show_times` relationship conditional, i.e. it would react to the `theatre_id` I pass to it and select only `show_times` with that id?

I need that to pass query params to my REST API built on top of these models, something like this:

http://my-api.com/movies?theatre_id=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done with SQLAlchemy's `bindparam()` function. A relationship is created for Movie model:

```
show_times = db.relationship(lambda: ShowTime,
                             primaryjoin=lambda: db.and_(
                                 Movie.id == ShowTime.movie_id,
                                 ShowTime.theatre_id == db.bindparam('theatre_id')))
```

Then a query would be something like this:

```
Movie.query.params(theatre_id=3).options(db.joinedload(Movie.show_times)).all()
```